# Is asking for constructive criticism on a question a legitimate meta question?

Tags: discussion, questions

I wrote a question, and it got down voted.
I'm not arguing, or upset, but I would like to understand what I did wrong, so that I will write better questions in the future (and increase their chance of getting answered).
Is it a legitimate question for meta, to post a link to a question and ask for constructive criticism? Also, are there other ways to get some proof reading/advice/mentoring etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say yes, this is an appropriate use of meta, so long as you focus on how to make your questions more on point.

We also have a [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat) where you can float rough questions around to other users of the site prior to asking them on the main site.

Comment: Regarding "other ways to get advice", maybe  browse https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-question and https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/question-quality ?